# Unity crashes when I destroy an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've made this code myself so I'm not sure what I've done wrong, I have a colider for my sword but whenever I get in range and swing my whole unity crashes

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class Attack : MonoBehaviour
{
    private CircleCollider2D cc2;
    private float x = 3;
    private Boolean timer = true;
    private Boolean hasAttacked = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        cc2.isTrigger = true;
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if(hasAttacked == false)
        {
            hasAttacked = true;
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0))
            {
                while (timer == true)
                {
                    x -= Time.deltaTime;
                }


                while (x >= 1)
                    if (collision.gameObject.name == "Enemy")
                    {
                        Destroy(GameObject.Find("Enemy"));
                    }

                if (x == 0)
                {
                    hasAttacked = false;
                    x = 3;
                }
            }

            
        }
    }
}
```

The Player is the parent of the sword if it makes a difference
It could be that they both try to destroy each other because the enemy is made to destroy the player

Comment: Have you used the debugger to verify that none of the while loops are endless loops?

Comment: Oh I never knew there was a debugger, the only thing I could think of is debug.log

Comment: **ALL** of your `while` loops are infinite loops ... within `while (timer == true)` the `timer` is never changed .... actually in your code it is **never ever** changed. And then also within `while (x >= 1)` the `x` is never changed either ...

Comment: ah I understand about the timer part, I thought it was run only once the if statement is true, I dont understand how 'x' isnt changed because i do 'x -= Time.deltaTime.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `while (timer == true)`. If it's true, then it will stuck in there. Also when you decreasing x by Time.deltaTime, there is a little chance it will equals with 0, you should check with `x <= 0`.

Also you should check for input in `Update`.

I would save the reference of the enemy in `OnCollisionEnter2D`, and clear that in `OnCollisionExit`, and handle the attack in the `Update`. Something like that:

```
private GameObject _enemy;
private float _actCooldown = 3.0f;

private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyKode.Mouse0) && _actCooldown <= 0.0f)
    {
        if (_enemy != null)
        {
            Destroy(_enemy);
            _enemy = null;
        }

        _actCooldown = 3.0f;
    }

    _actCooldown -= Time.deltaTime;
}

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.name.Equals("Enemy")) _enemy = collision.gameObject;
}

private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject == _enemy) _enemy = null;
}
```

Of course if there are more enemies, you'll have to add more logic to it.

Comment: Ah ok it looks good I’ll try it tommorow thanks